# Mechanical USB interrupt

Tags: usb, interrupts

I'm quite the noob to USB controllers. I want to create a mechanical interrupt for USB power for a connected device.

Long story.  Car has a USB a connection (probably3.0) for the stereo/phone connection. I'm looking to use a wireless Android autobox such as Motorola MA1 but I want to tuck it into the dash so it's not visible. I know sometimes the unit can need a reset. I am looking to put a mechanical momentary switch in the dash so I can cut power to it for reset.

Can I cut the connection by opening Vbus with a momentary switch? Am I possibly inducing damaging currents by just opening Vbus to either the host(expensive factory stereo) or connected module?

Comment: What kind of USB?  Note that Type-C connectors have different requirements, and signal with CC, not with VBUS.

Comment: Sounds fine. That's what happens when you unplug the cable anyway.